# trying to debug my python code but settrace not executing

Tags: python, debugging, sys

I already have python 2.7 installed on windows but whenever i run my code this line doesn't work , the debug process is not executed !!

```
sys.settrace(traceit)
```

Here is the code

```
import sys
import pyreadline



def remove_html_markup(s):
tag = False
quote = False
out = ""

for c in s:
    if c == '<' and not quote:
        tag = True
    elif c == '>' and not quote:
        tag = False
    elif c == '"' or c == "'" and tag:
        quote = not quote
    elif not tag:
        out = out + c
return out



def main():
    print remove_html_markup('xyz')
    print remove_html_markup('"<b>foo</b>"')
    print remove_html_markup("'<b>foo</b>'")



breakpoints = {9: True}
stepping = False



def debug(command, my_locals):
    global stepping
    global breakpoints

    if command.find(' ') > 0:
        arg = command.split(' ')[1]
    else:
        arg = None

    if command.startswith('s'):  # step
        stepping = True
        return True
    elif command.startswith('c'):  # continue
        stepping = False
        return True
    elif command.startswith('p'):    # print
        stepping = False
        return True

    elif command.startswith('q'):  # quit
        sys.exit(0)
    else:
        print "No such command", repr(command)

    return False


commands = ["p", "s", "p tag", "p foo", "q"]


def input_command():
    # command = raw_input("(my-spyder) ")
    global commands
    command = commands.pop(0)
    return command


def traceit(frame, event, trace_arg):
    global stepping

    if event == 'line':
        if stepping or breakpoints.has_key(frame.f_lineno):
            resume = False
            while not resume:
                print event, frame.f_lineno, frame.f_code.co_name, frame.f_locals
                command = input_command()
                resume = debug(command, frame.f_locals)
    return traceit



sys.settrace(traceit)
main()
sys.settrace(None)
```

The output should be

```
line 9 remove_html_markup {'s': 'xyz'}
line 10 remove_html_markup {'s': 'xyz', 'tag': False}
line 11 remove_html_markup {'quote': False, 's': 'xyz', 'tag': False}
line 13 remove_html_markup {'quote': False, 's': 'xyz', 'tag': False, 'out': ''}
line 14 remove_html_markup {'quote': False, 's': 'xyz', 'tag': False, 'c': 'x', 'out': ''}
```

but it returns

```
xyz
<b>foo</b>
'foo'
```

I need to know how to fix this problem , i'm new to debugging and i really need to learn debugging to improve my skills and reduce time taken to fix bugs

Comment: i think you want to use `import pdb...pdb.set_trace()`

Comment: I appreciate your answer , it's just i'm taking the (Software Debugging) course on udacity and they used sys module to debug i just need to know why it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

After trying so hard , i realized that my Python 2.7.5 didn't work , when i updated it to 2.7.14 but the same happened , then i realized that at the top of my code there was this line

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Since i was using windows this line of code shouldn't even exist so once i removed it things went so great and the code worked !